# how do I make rxjava pagination

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2, mvp

I am trying to add pagination to my rest call here, and I have looked at many tuts but I don't know how I make pagination from this call in my Presenter, so I can handle pages from my REST API? in my `Json` I have this:

"pages": 22,
"page": 1,

```
    public class NearbyUsersPresenter implements NearbyUsersPresenterInterface {

    NearbyUsersViewInterface mvi;
    private String TAG = "NearbyUsersPresenter";
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private volatile int pageNumber = 1;

    public NearbyUsersPresenter(NearbyUsersViewInterface mvi) {
        this.mvi = mvi;
    }

    @Override
    public void getMessages() {
        getObservable().subscribeWith(getObserver());
    }

    public Observable<NearbyUsersList> getObservable(){
        db = new SQLiteHandler(mvi.getContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
        final String apiKey = user.get("apiKey");
        return RestClient.getClient().create(REST.class)
                            .NearbyUsers(apiKey, pageNumber, 20)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }

    public DisposableObserver<NearbyUsersList> getObserver(){
        return new DisposableObserver<NearbyUsersList>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull NearbyUsersList nearbyUsersList) {
                mvi.displayNearbyUsers(nearbyUsersList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Error"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                mvi.displayError("Error fetching NearbyUsers Data");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d(TAG,"Completed");
                mvi.hideProgressBar();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: So What Problem are u facing?

Comment: That I dont know how to add pagination to my presenter, I have trying to look at this code here: https://github.com/sandrfx/ListCase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sandrlab/listcase/presentation/repos_list/presenter/GitReposListPresenter.java but without any luck :(

Comment: take a look into this new Android Native Library -> [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/)